# Logout flow in play! framework 2.0, java

Tags: java, playframework-2.0

I ran into this problem yesterday and haven't been able to find a solution to it.

Once a user logs out how do I prevent them from hitting the back button and loading the cached, previous page?

I ran into this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16702356/play-framework-wont-logout-with-secure-module) and read the suggested article, but I'm unsure if any of these suggestions are the correct way to handle this problem.

I even ran the sample apps from Play! notably the Forms app and it has the same problem. I thought their apps would at least show how to handle this.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable the cache in the response's header (no-cache or must revalidate) for every page that needs to check the credentials.

Comment: OK, I think that will for now. I'll try it. I'm not building a huge application but if I was, would this be a viable option?

Comment: Well... I believe that if your content is really sensitive, you shouldn't have it in the cache anyway (user's cache, not yours). But most websites do not try to fix this anyway, and allow to go back even after logout (just tried on my bank, github does it on some pages).

Comment: @Maxime - Can you please elaborate this with code. Please.I tried with these     
     response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
     response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "public");
     response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "max-age=0");